# Is this a PHP bug?

Tags: php, debugging

```
<?php 
/* PHP devs, test & tell me I'm crazy. */ 
$x[] = '1'; 
if (empty($x[0]['x'])) {
  echo 'No PHP bug.';
} 
else {
  echo 'PHP bug exists.';
} 
?>
```

I always get "PHP bug exists."

```
<?php 
/* PHP devs, test & tell me I'm crazy. */ 
$x[] = 1; 
if (empty($x[0]['x'])) {
  echo 'No PHP bug.';
} 
else {
  echo 'PHP bug exists.';
} 
?>
```

Outputs "No PHP bug."

```
<?php 
/* PHP devs, test & tell me I'm crazy. */ 
$x[] = '1'; 
if (!isset($x[0]['x'])) {
  echo 'No PHP bug.';
} 
else {
  echo 'PHP bug exists.';
} 
?>
```

Outputs "PHP bug exists."

```
<?php 
/* PHP devs, test & tell me I'm crazy. */ 
$x[] = '1'; 
if (!isset($x[0]['hello world'])) {
  echo 'No PHP bug.';
} 
else {
  echo 'PHP bug exists.';
} 
?>
```

Outputs "PHP bug exists."

Comment: you are converting a scalar to an array probably something to do with that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because you are assigning a string to the array. Because of that, the `x` in `$x[0]['x']` gets auto-cast into `0` - remember, the second indes is not pointing to an array, but a string, which can't have non-numeric indexes.

`$x[0][0]` indeed exists - it's the first character of the string.

`$x[0][1]` does **not** exist, and your test returns the correct result if you change the index accordingly:

```
if (isset($x[0][0])) echo "0 index is set."; 
if (isset($x[0][1])) echo "1 index is not set.";
```

Lesson: Even though strings can be accessed like arrays, they aren't arrays.

There's a [warning in the PHP manual page on strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) explaining the behaviour:

> Writing to an out of range offset pads the string with spaces. Non-integer types are converted to integer. Illegal offset type emits E_NOTICE. Negative offset emits E_NOTICE in write but reads empty string. Only the first character of an assigned string is used. Assigning empty string assigns NULL byte.

Comment: So would you consider the auto casting here to be a PHP bug?

Comment: @mikey not really. It works as designed - it's a bit unintuitive (I agree the behaviour you originally expected would feel more right) but it behaves as described

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug.

```
$x[] = '1';
```

This makes an array like so: `array(1)`.

So `$x[0] == '1'`.

When you do `$x[0]['x']`, you are doing `"1"['x']`.

The `'x'` is converted to `0`, and `"1"[0] == "1"`, which isn't empty.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with the way that you can access a string character by character.

```
$x[0]['x']
```

is equivalent to

```
$x = '1';
$x['x'];
```

since you are accessing a string using `[]`, it would convert the index to an integer in that case 'x' would convert to 0, so it would extract the first character '1'

here a demo:

```
$x[] = '1';
var_dump($x[0]['x']);
```